# Something wrong with '~--'

Tags: android, operator-keyword

I am reading a book about android.
By typing Code, I got a problem, I also checked if I typed something wrong. But Nop, everything allriight.
(And could you please explain to me what '~--' means?)
Thanks a lot guys. I appreciate your help. 
[image]

Comment: In Php you can find ~ operator which is a bit operator and works as inversion. See here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php but in Java i haven't used it anywhere.

Comment: There must be an error in the book. ~--  makes no sense.

Comment: If `~--` really written in your book, then it is a bug. This line should read: `betragNetto = betrag - betragUst;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid Java.  There is no ~-- operator, so that's why you're seeing that error.